# Pandas manipulating strings in two columns

Tags: string, pandas

Here is my dataframe:

```
           A                B
0   asdf|afsdf|fasd    sdsd|wer|wer
1   sdfsdf             sdfsdff
2   sdf|s              sdfsde|sdf
```

I would like to form column `C` which would contain concatenated values from column  `A` and column `B` up to first `|`, and if `|` is not present, then it will simply concatenate two columns. Also while concatenating I would like to insert `--`
here is how column `C` should look like:

```
         C
0   asdf--sdsd
1   sdfsdf--sdfsdff
2   sdf--sdfsde
```

I can go through every single row with `df.loc` and get what I need, but it is slow and I wonder if there is faster way of doing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer using `str` and `split`

```
df['C'] = df.A.str.split('|').str.get(0).add('--') \
        + df.B.str.split('|').str.get(0)
df
```

[image]

---

You can expand this out further

```
df['C'] = df.A.str.split('|', expand=True).stack() \
    .add('--').add(df.B.str.split('|', expand=True).stack()) \
    .groupby(level=0).apply('|'.join)
df
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

There may be a more fancy way, but this works:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: d = {'A': ('asdf|afsdf|fasd', 'sdfsdf', 'sdf|s'),
             'B': ('sdsd|wer|wer', 'sdfsdff', 'sdfsde|sdf')}

In [3]: data = pd.DataFrame(d)

In [4]: data['C'] = data['A'].str.split('|').str.get(0) + "--" + data['B'].str.split('|').str.get(0)

In [5]: data
Out[5]: 
                 A             B                 C
0  asdf|afsdf|fasd  sdsd|wer|wer       asdf--sdsd
1           sdfsdf       sdfsdff  sdfsdf--sdfsdff
2            sdf|s    sdfsde|sdf      sdf--sdfsde
```

References on working with strings in `pandas` can be found in [their documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html).